# What package to use for Form + intelligent Answer website?

Tags: google-app-engine, web, lamp, bitnami

I'm new to web developing and I want to make a web where the user fill in a few info and then get an answer from the backend. The info filled in is sent to the backend; the backend then process the info and send the answer back for display.

My question is how can I do it with the simplest possible framework? LAMP and GAE both seem ok to me in the long run, but is there any simpler framework good for my needs? I have also looked into LAMP provider like bitnami, however I can't find the application I need in the list of applications. If needed, I can program in Java.

Thanks! and please let me know if I need to clarify my question. I think what I'm asking is general guidance on setting up such a simple web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google AppEngine will work fine for your needs.  You will need to program it, and Java works on GAE.  Start with [Java Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction) and then gradually add your own server side processing.  Of course many other web server platforms are possible, but users of GAE generally consider it to be very capable and easy enough to use.  LAMP is likely to take you longer to learn.